# How to capitalise the first letter of the keyboard return key

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Swift iOS, How can you capitalise the first letter of the keyboard return key without affecting the rest of the keyboard?

In particular I need to capitalise the N for the "next" key in the keyboard.

Comment: What if the user uses a keyboard of a different language, especially one without capital letters? Like Japanese/Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom keyboard, its simple.

here you can see more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html